# iPad: How to change the tint color of a navigation bar item in a popover?

Tags: ios, ipad, popover, navbar, tint

I am using a custom popoverBackgroundViewClass to tint the popover to dark gray.

https://github.com/Scianski/KSCustomUIPopover

```
popover.popoverBackgroundViewClass = [KSCustomPopoverBackgroundView class];
```

Works great, but how do I change a popover's navigation item's tint? The "back" button in the popover's nav bar is still the standard blue color.

Answer (score 0):

The contentViewController you've specified is obviously a UINavigationController right?
Which has a rootViewController. So something like the following from the rootViewController:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

...should do it.